# Can't align the imagine into the center of the page

Tags: html, css

HTML page code:

```
<main>
        <img src="https://c.tenor.com/rv04dG_HDH0AAAAi/jojo-thonk.gif" alt="Nu se incarca" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>O imagine mult mai smechera, si acum este aliniata </p>
        <p id="wild">SUNT complet diferit de restul paragrafelor</p>    
    </main>
```

CSS code:

```
main{
    
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

main > p{
    
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    
}

img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    /*padding: 15px;*/
   
    
}
.caption {
    display: block;
}
```

I can't seem to align the picture into the center of the page properly, I tried removing the margin of *main* but I can't get anything to work.

This is how it looks:
https://gyazo.com/f948f9f93ee3c448d5879a9c9eca17fb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using flexboxes this way.

- add a class to your container

```
<main class="container">
        <img src="https://c.tenor.com/rv04dG_HDH0AAAAi/jojo-thonk.gif" alt="Nu se incarca" />
        <p>O imagine mult mai smechera, si acum este aliniata </p>
        <p id="wild">SUNT complet diferit de restul paragrafelor</p>    
</main>
```

- add styling

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column; /* change elements direction from row to column */
  gap: 20px; /* Vertical Gap instead of using <br> */
}
```

That should do it better than margins and paddings that may cause potential issues in other displays.

More on how to use flexboxes [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

This [beautiful game](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) should give you some practice as well :)

Comment: Happy to hear that. Could you check it as valid so other developers will easily spot it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix to your code.

- Add `text-align: center;` to `main`
- Add `max-width: 500px; width: 100%;` to `main>p`

```css
main {

    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

main>p {

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;

}

img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    /*padding: 15px;*/


}

.caption {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <img src="https://c.tenor.com/rv04dG_HDH0AAAAi/jojo-thonk.gif" alt="Nu se incarca" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>O imagine mult mai smechera, si acum este aliniata </p>
    <p id="wild">SUNT complet diferit de restul paragrafelor</p>
</main>
```